# Cleaning a wordpress database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, code-cleanup, wpml

I have a wordpress site and after a bug caused by WPML, thousands of ghost duplicated images where created.

I manually deleted them but looking at the database, all the links are still there, even if the images are gone.

Here is an exemple of 1 line:

```
(8447, 2, '2015-05-21 10:27:36', '2015-05-21 14:27:36', '', 'bonaventure', '', 'inherit', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'bonaventure-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-481', '', '', '2015-05-21 10:27:36', '2015-05-21 14:27:36', '', 266, 'http://www.langloisphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bonaventure.jpg', 0, 'attachment', 'image/jpeg', 0);
```

Is there a way to clean the database, as far as it got big for nothing ?

Comment: You will probably want to include which WP table(s) you're referencing. If they are sequential, you may be able to delete the range by primary key. Be sure you backup your database immediately before with mysqldump in case you mess up - better yet, script it out in a test / development environment, if possible!

Comment: Create a query that selects all these duplicates.